# How do I alter a XML-File based on the content of tags

Tags: xml, xml-parsing

I have files in XML format with more than 3k lines.

The structure is always the same and corresponds to this in repetition:

```
...
<Placemark>
        <name> Text</name>
        <description><![CDATA[]]></description>
        <Point>
            <coordinates>x, y, z</coordinates>
        </Point>
        <Style>
            <IconStyle>
                <Icon>
                    icon
                </Icon>
            </IconStyle>
        </Style>
</Placemark>
...
```

I want to change the `Style` block based on info from the `name` and the `description`, so if a certain word occurs, replace the existing `Style` block with a certain other `Style` block. There will be less than 20 different `Style` blocks and "trigger words". The whole thing is supposed to run once for each file.

If I have to code something, in which language and with which frameworks?
Or do you know of an application that can do this?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a job for XSLT. You could start with an identity transform and add specialized templates for each of the "trigger words" that generate different `Style` content, depending upon whether the `name` or `description` have any of the "trigger words".

An example XSLT with specialized `Style` templates for "triggerWord" and "otherTriggerWord":

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
    
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
    
  <xsl:template match="Placemark[(name,description)[contains(., 'triggerWord')]]/Style">
    <Style>
      <!--custom style content for triggerWord-->
    </Style>
  </xsl:template>
    
    
  <xsl:template match="Placemark[(name,description)[contains(., 'otherTriggerWord')]]/Style">
    <Style>
      <!--custom style content for otherTriggerWord-->
    </Style>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```